# Is it possible to add a second correct answer to the lockscreen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

My boss has requested me of making a solution to the company's android mobile phones to secure our data.
The problem is that I am a Python programmer, and have not used the Java language for some time, my other problem is, that I don't think what he actually ask for is possible without using a custom rom for the phones.

What he wants is a solution so when the worker is greeted with his/her lock screen on the phone they have two options:
1. Enter normal code, will just unlock the phone as normal.
2. Enter Special code, unlocks the phone, and allow acces to our servers.

Of my knowledge that should not be possible, but he insist that I should check it, if it is an option.

So my question is simple, is it even possible? if not my go to will be to just add a login screen when opening the company application even tho he wants the other option.

God day to everyone!

P.S I am not asking for a code solution, that I will try to figure out myself, my question is just if it's possible, due to my time is limited for the this project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible on android without modifying the OS and maintaining it yourself for future android versions.

Depending on what your boss means by "allow acces to our servers", a **mobile device management** solution and android's **work profile** might be an option.

This way, there can be separate apps for private and business use. Users can be forced to [enable a lock screen](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6328679) but there is alway only one loockscreen for both, private and business apps.

You can test it here by creating a demo company: https://enterprise.google.com/android/experience/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer. 
We might end up using your first solution, or as a backup solution use Python via Kivy and implement a credentials solution.

But once again thanks for your answer! 
I can't give you 1+ due to i'm a new member here, but you deserve it.

Good day to everyone.